# Need help finding 2nd order Taylor polynomial of function

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a function

$$g(t)=t^{8}\rm e^{t-1}$$

I need to (by hand) find the 2nd order Taylor polynomial for $g(t)$ in $(1,g(1))$

I get:
$$g(1)=1$$
$$g'(1)=8\cdot1^7\rm e^{1-1}+t^8\cdot\rm e^{1-1}=9$$
$$g''(1)=56\cdot1^6\rm e^{1-1}+16\cdot1^7\rm e^{1-1}+t^8\rm e^{1-1}=73$$

I use the Taylor formula and get:

$$\tilde{g}_2(t)=1+9(t-1)+\frac{73}{2}=8+9\,t+{\frac {73\, \left( t-1 \right) ^{2}}{2}}$$

When I use Maple's mtayloer function, however, the first term 8 is negative.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: How comes  you obtain a linear and a quadratic polynomials?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you elaborate on what you mean specifically?

Comment: Notice that $9(t-1) = 9t \color{red}{-}9$.

Comment: Why are the l.h.s. and the r.h.s. of the very last equality different?

Comment: I see my error now, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taylor polynomial in question is

$$1+9\,(t-1)+{\frac {73\, \left( t-1 \right) ^{2}}{2}}.$$

Comment: Perhaps you should expand $(t-1)^2$ and group the constant and linear terms?